# What does the -R switch mean when used with chmod or chown commands?

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

I'm just trying to get up to speed with permissions in Linux. I've come across an example which uses `-R` when changing permissions and ownership of a directory.

What does the `-R` mean?

Comment: `man chown` or `info chown` or `chown --help` all contain your answer.

Comment: What have you been doing to get up to speed. Where do you get your example from that includes usage without explanation?

Comment: hmm, my attempt to get the answer this morning (while still half asleep) was browsing around the internet for 10 minutes.


Also I have just dusted off my linux / unix book from 1998 which I'm hoping will help!

I take it I should have done a little bit more research myself before posting the question :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man chown`

```
   -R, --recursive
          change files and directories recursively
```